# Unable to programmatically create tags in GitHub - ISO8601 timestamp is invalid

Tags: laravel, github

In my lumen app I'm trying to programmatically create tags a GitHub repo.  My setup is working great except something is up with the `tagger.date` that I can't figure out.  The API is telling me that the timestamp is not valid:

```
[Github\Exception\RuntimeException]                 
  Invalid request.                                    
  2016-07-10T13:32:07+0000 is not a valid date-time.
```

However the timestamp included in the error message appears to be correctly formatted [based on the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/#create-a-tag-object).

```
    $github->git()->tags()->create(
        $githubConfig['namespace'],
        $githubConfig['repository'],
        [
            'tag'       => $this->version->patchTag(),
            'tagger'    => [
                'name'  => config('github.tagger.name'),
                'email' => config('github.tagger.email'),
                'date'  => Carbon::now()->toIso8601String()
            ],
            'message'   => 'This release was automatically published by [Game-Watcher](https://github.com/bkuhl/game-watcher).',
            'object'    => $masterBranch['commit']['sha'],
            'type'      => 'commit'
        ]
    );
```

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wq7tjec7/14/) indicates the time format is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Carbon::now()->toAtomString()` instead.

Carbon's [common formatting methods](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats) are "wrappers for the common formats provided in the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)".

The documentation for `DateTime::ISO8601` carries this warning:

> **Note:** This format is not compatible with ISO-8601, but is left this way for backward compatibility reasons. Use `DateTime::ATOM` or `DATE_ATOM` for compatibility with ISO-8601 instead.

The relevant difference appears to be with the timezone offset. `DateTime::ISO8601` uses `+0000` for UTC, while `DateTime::ATOM` uses `+00:00`.

Comment: It's incredibly frustrating that they left that for backward compatibility and even more so that Carbon doesn't fix this.

Comment: Agreed, @Webnet. IMO this is something that should have been fixed, particularly because of problems like yours. Developers should be able to assume that `ISO8601` actually reflects the standard for which it's named. I'm surprised it wasn't fixed in PHP7.

Comment: It did work, thank you.  I've marked it as the answer (I thought I already had)

Comment: Great! I was pretty sure it would, but it's nice to have confirmation.